# Rails 3: ActiveResource custom method call - ClientError 414 - Work around?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, methods, activeresource

I'm currently creating both the client and server app using ActiveResource for web servicing. The client has a long string (:history) that needs a conversion process done by the server.

Here, the client calls the post method on my object which extends ActiveResource::Base

```
active_resource.post(:convert, {:history => hh, :format => format})
```

This line errors complaining that the URI is too long:

ActiveResource::ClientError Failed.  Response code = 414.  Response message = Request-URI Too Large.

What other options do I have for sending "large" data ? Probably looking in the neighborhood of 2000 characters of data for the hh string above.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So the signature for the post method is:

```
post(custom_method_name, options = {}, body = '')
```

So, when you do:

```
active_resource.post(:convert, {:history => hh, :format => format})
```

It's putting your post variables in the options hash, which comes out in your query string for the post.

What you want to do is:

```
active_resource.post(:convert, nil, {:history => hh, :format => format}.to_json)
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't think post parameters factored into URI length.  Are you sure it's the hh string and not the actual URI that active_resource.post is using?